# Update ViewModel in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm new to Knockout. I'm trying to develop a *Shopping Cart* functionality using Knockout.

My problem is when I want to put a **Counter** in my cart, the counter will be applied to all the cart contents.

```js
var FoodVM = function() {
  self.ID = ko.observable();
  self.Name = ko.observable();
  self.Price = ko.observable();
  self.Clicks = ko.observable(0);

  self.clickCounterAdd = function() {
    self.Clicks(self.Clicks() + 1);
  };
};

var FoodsListVM = function() {
  this.FoodsList = ko.observableArray([new FoodVM()]);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var model = new FoodsListVM();
  ko.applyBindings(model);

  var data = [{
      ID: 1,
      Name: "Test 1",
      Price: 25000
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      Name: "Test 2",
      Price: 30000
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      Name: "Test 3",
      Price: 35000
    }
  ];

  model.FoodsList(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Add</th>
    <th>Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: FoodsList">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: clickCounterAdd" style="width: 73px;">Add</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Clicks" style="width: 20px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sina_saeedi82/tx7o6qgu/) demo.

Could you please tell me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake is forgetting to define `self` in your `FoodVM`.

```
var self = this;
```

Because of this you were attaching all the observables and the `clickCounterAdd` function to whatever `self` happened to be in the global scope, not to your viewmodel.

The next mistake is that you initialize your `FoodsList` property with a single  `FoodVM`...

```
this.FoodsList = ko.observableArray([new FoodVM()]);
```

...but a few moments later you overwrite that with a simple JS object, `data`.

```
model.FoodsList(data);
```

That means the one `FoodVM` is lost - and the items in `data` do not become `FoodVM`s on their own. Some kind of loop is necessary to turn the plain objects in the data array into `FoodVM` instances. Usually this is done through a `.map()` call.

---

Here is a better approach to viewmodel building.

Write your viewmodels in such a way that they initialize themselves from a parameter object (i.e. from the model). Make the property names of your data match the property names of your viewmodel.

```
function someViewmodel(params) {
    this.data = ko.observable(params.data);
}
```

In your case there are two viewmodels, `Food` and `FoodsList` (I find it redundant to call them `*VM`, so I'm not doing that). I've added one level to the model (`foods`) to match the equally-named property in the `FoodsList`.

```js
var Food = function(params) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.ID = ko.observable(params.ID);
  self.Name = ko.observable(params.Name);
  self.Price = ko.observable(params.Price);

  self.clicks = ko.observable(0);
  self.countClick = function () {
    self.clicks(self.clicks() + 1);
  };
};

var FoodsList = function(params) {
  var self = this; 

  self.foods = ko.observableArray(params.foods.map(function (item) {
    return new Food(item);
  }));
};


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var model = {
  foods: [
    { ID: 1, Name: "Test 1", Price: 25000 },
    { ID: 2, Name: "Test 2", Price: 30000 },
    { ID: 3, Name: "Test 3", Price: 35000 }
  ]
};

var vm = new FoodsList(model);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Add</th>
    <th>Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: foods">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Price"></td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="click: countClick" style="width: 73px;">Add</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: clicks" style="width: 20px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note how everything bootstraps itself during initialization, `new FoodsList(model)` builds an entire, nested viewmodel.

Incidentally this task is so common that there is a knockout plugin that does it for you: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html. Take some time to read its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

look the changes below

```
var Food = function(params) {
  var self = this;

  self.ID = ko.observable(params.ID);
  self.Name = ko.observable(params.Name);
  self.Price = ko.observable(params.Price);

  self.clicks = ko.observable(0);
  self.countClick = function () {
    self.clicks(self.clicks() + 1);
  };
};

var FoodsList = function(params) {
  var self = this; 

  self.foods = ko.observableArray(params.foods.map(function (item) {
    return new Food(item);
  }));
};


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var model = {
  foods: [
    { ID: 1, Name: "Test 1", Price: 25000 },
    { ID: 2, Name: "Test 2", Price: 30000 },
    { ID: 3, Name: "Test 3", Price: 35000 }
  ]
};

var vm = new FoodsList(model);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```